# Invoking a specific Powershell function from Ansible

Tags: function, powershell, ansible

Apologies for an ultra newbie question. In Ansible, I can download a Powershell script onto a remote Windows server. The script has a function that I would like to run remotely, but I haven't been able to work out how to do this. I've done extensive searching without success, which tells me that I'm asking the wrong question.

Any help would be appreciated.

NEW - More detail might help. Let's assume that the PS script is called exchange.ps1, that includes several functions. These functions include fn_a and fn_b, and fn_b appears after fn_a. We'll say that each function requires an argument. How would I invoke fn_b? I'm doing all the other necessaty things such as running WinRM, have Kerberos authentication working etc.

Comment: I googled "Ansible run powershell script" and found instantly a plausible looking example on their github for running powershell scripts -> https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/windows/run-powershell.yml ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can run functions directly by setting a parameter in powershell:

Call:

```
myscript.ps1 my_function 
myscript.ps1 second_funtion
```

Script layout

```
switch ($args[0]) {
 my_funtion() {
   echo "Hello World"
 }
 second_function() {
   echo"blah"
 }
}
```